# Sound stopped working after 14.04 update

Tags: 14.04, sound, dell

I have no sound on Ubuntu 14.04 since about a week now, but Bluetooth speaker and Bluetooth headphones work.
I must have been an update doing it, because a friend of mine has the same problem with an identical laptop — while another friend with the same laptop has no problems, because he does not believe in doing updates.

The Sound Settings shows **Dummy Output** only.

Laptop: Dell Inspiron 15 3551

Does anybody know anything about this problem?

---

This question was regarding the original installation on a Dell Inspiron 15 3551 (64bit). I have another 14.04 installation on an older 32bit laptop, which was unaffected — if that is of any interest to anybody.

Since I am now organising my new 18.04 installation, the question is no longer relevant to me. And since no solution was found, anybody that thinks it appropriate is welcome to delete this post. I don't believe I would have the authority to do so. Thank you.

Comment: Reminder: Ubuntu 14.04 will reach EOL and lose community support next month.

Comment: If you enter the command `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` does your sound output device come back?

Comment: @user535733: I'm planning to update to 18.04 end of next month. But it still would have been nice with sound till than. I guess I can make do with Bluetooth.

Comment: @Charles Green: I just tried that, and did a restart for good measure. But I'm afraid it made no difference. But as I just said, I might as well make do with Bluetooth until the upgrade.

Comment: Do you by any chance, have timidity installed?

Comment: Also, please append your question with the output of the command `aplay -l`

Comment: Nope, never heard of timidity. I also did a search and nothing came up.

Comment: Result for aplay -l was: aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...